# Can't run Gatsby because of incorrect node version detection

Tags: node.js, gatsby

After running "rpm run develop"
Error: Gatsby requires Node.js 18.0.0 or higher (your version is v16.20.1).

When I run 'node -v', I get: v18.19.0

Which means my node version is okay

I have tried several solutions based on Co-Pilot suggestions, but none have worked. These attempts included deleting npm packages and reinstalling them, setting the default NPM version, adding a .nvm file, and editing the 'engines' field in package.json."

Update:
Here is my node -ls:

```
      v14.21.3
       v16.20.1
       v18.17.0
       v18.19.0
->      v20.5.0
         system
default -> 20.5.0 (-> v20.5.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v20.5.0) (default)
stable -> 20.5 (-> v20.5.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/iron (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.19.0
lts/iron -> v20.10.0 (-> N/A)
```

I uninstalled 16.2.1 version, but still getting this nasty message.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple node versions installed at once in different paths.

Comment: Maybe, how can I check that? I'm using NVM and that worked fine for some time, then something stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by uninstalling NVM, Node and installing it again